# Defining a Class method vs Passing object as parameter to an Function in OOP

Tags: python, oop, object-oriented-analysis

We havce 2 ways to change state of an object

We create a method in the class and invoke it to change the state. example

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.car_color = color

    # this method may have complex logic of computing the next color. for simplicity, I created this method just like a setter.
    def change_color(self, new_color):
        self.car_color = new_color
```

Or we can pass object of class to a method and change the state. example

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.car_color = color
    # these are just getters and setter and wont have complicated logic while setting color.
    def set_color(self, new_color):
        self.car_color = new_color
    def get_color(self):
        return self.car_color

# this method will have all the complicated logic to be performed while changing color of car.
def change_color(car_object, new_color):
    car_object.set_color(new_color)
```

Which of the above approach is better in terms Object oriented programming?
I have done 2nd approach all the time but now I am little confused regarding which one is better.

Comment: Go with the first...

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as you understand your own code. But if I were you, I would prefer the 1st approach.

Comment: can the same be said for the save of the object? let's say we want to persist the object in some DB. should save function be part of object or should it be a separate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a third approach, instantiate the object with the new color itself, and define an external function which takes the old color and returns the new color

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.car_color = color

#A function which takes in the old_color and provides the new color
def logic_to_change_color(old_color):
    #do stuff
    return new_color

car = Car(logic_to_change_color(old_color))
```

Otherwise the first option is the best, since it keeps all the methods related to the `Car` class within the definition itself, which the second option doesn't do, where you need to explicitly pass the object to the function, (In the first option, the class instance is accessed by `self`)

Comment: can the same be said for the save of the object? let's say we want to persist the object in some DB. should save function be part of object or should it be a separate function?

Comment: Depends on how you define `persistance`, look up examples in python libraries like `SQLAlchemy` to check how they do that perhaps? Maybe take a look at this qustion here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264985/saving-an-object-via-a-method-of-its-own-or-via-another-class

Comment: Let me know if you have any more questions @hello123 And if the answer helped you, please consider marking the answer as accepted :)